# How to update snap-store linux.. How to update this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to update snap-store .

I don't  have Ubuntu advantage subscription.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Questions need text to be questions. Use the EDIT button and fix your... thing here to make it into an actual question.

Comment: Have you run updates as suggested? I could see in Ubuntu SNAP being updated in the course of regular updates. Log into Live Patch.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Go to terminal and kill the snap-store process before installing/refreshing snap-store.

Find process with `ps aux | grep snap`

Find  for the snap-store process, which looks like this

```
... <process id> ... ... /snap/snap-store/???/usr/bin/snap-store.
```

Kill process using the above found process id:

```
kill <process id>
```

Install/refresh snap-store:

Close "Ubuntu software" gnome app if it open.

Refresh snap-store:

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

Had the same problem and fixed it this way.

Comment: that works on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: "pkill snap-store" works fine as well

Comment: Adding to this: running "sudo snap refresh snap-store" directly with running processes will return an error including the pid of the running processes so you know what to run kill on.

Comment: Should snap-store be restarted?

Comment: I've rolled this answer into a single command line executable, and also made a desktop shortcut  https://github.com/levis501/snap_refresh

Comment: `sudo pkill snap-store && sudo snap refresh snap-store` (copied from [askubuntu.com/a/1411573/822591](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411573/822591)) works on Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Imagine designing a new and improved package system and not giving it a facility to update itself but throwing warnings and error messages instead.

Comment: Another answer way down the list suggest to first use `snap-store --quit` before using any kill variant. Kill commands should be reserved for situations with no alternative, as they can damage a running process.

Answer (score 57):

I had same issue.

```shell
$ killall snap-store
$ snap refresh
```

worked for me.

If this still doesn't work, it means that your snap-store isn't a fresh install. You already have snap desktop integration running on your machine.
Stop the running process manually by using:
$ ps -ef | grep snap (it gets you the running process id)
$ sudo kill 1997 (replace your process id here)

let me know, if it works :-)
your feedback helps us improve the answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: @Community No, it couldn't.

Comment: I still wonder: Is this a bug? Will the snap-store ever get its updates if we don't intervene? But I know it is very important that snaps are not updated while the app is running because it will most likely cause the app to crash. (refresh-app-awareness is a good thing.)

Comment: 2024 and I still needed to do this from command line

Answer (score 11):

Other possible way:

Check the process, and note the id:

```
ps auxww | grep snap-store
```

Quit snap-store:

```
snap-store --quit
```

Check if the process is stopped

```
ps auxww | grep snap-store
```

If so, refresh snap-store:

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

Comment: Appreciate using the built-in method `snap-store --quit` instead of randomly killing PIDs

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1412580/25344

Answer (score 8):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and this worked perfect for me.

- $ pkill snap-store
- $ sudo snap refresh snap-store

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is your answer better than the accepted one? Please do not just copy someone else’s answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just run this command:

`sudo snap refresh snap-store`

It will show the information about running snap apps

```
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps
       (ubuntu-software), pids: 2247
```

Then kill them. and run again same command:

```
kill 2247
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

replace 2247 with whatever you see after `pids:`

Answer (score 0):

Run Ubuntu Update (Left Icon bar or Applications  ....).

If it updates, wait and then see settings.  Go to and configure Live Patch.

If it is not updating, you will see settings right away and configure Live Patch

[image: Live Patch]

..

If already updating, you should see that Live Patch is configured (likely) and nothing left to do.

If not running you will need to enable it which probably means signing in (it did mean that for me)

Updates will update Snap (Updates Tab) automatically.

Comment: In which Ubuntu version is this? I can't find any "Ubuntu Update" software in 22.20, just Ubuntu Software

Comment: That was V20.04 when I posted;  I set up 22.04 the same way.